# How to make a Drupal Commerce configuration entity revisionable

Tags: drupal, json-api, drupal-commerce, drupal-content-types, drupal-entities

I have an Ember application on the frontend consuming Drupal's JSONAPI.

Drupal has the commerce module installed.

The ember application is requesting all product_types, and needs to display information about the product types.

The product type has fields on it such as description variationType and label, but as an anonymous user, I cannot see all these attributes, only label.

It seems like this is an issue with the way The commerce module checks permissions.

```
if (!$access->isAllowed()) {
      // If this is the default revision or the entity is not revisionable, then
      // check access to the entity label. Revision support is all or nothing.
      if (!$entity->getEntityType()->isRevisionable() || $entity->isDefaultRevision()) {
        $label_access = $entity->access('view label', NULL, TRUE);
        $entity->addCacheableDependency($label_access);
        if ($label_access->isAllowed()) {
          return LabelOnlyResourceObject::createFromEntity($resource_type, $entity);
```

In the wild -- https://github.com/Free5Dev/drupalMagellium/blob/f5b0344a528a1df788c94e7558a6826dc9a2f736/core/modules/jsonapi/src/Access/EntityAccessChecker.php#L181

Here jsonapi decides to render a limited version of the entity.

It seems like this entity needs to be made revisionable in order to pass the above check and be fully rendered.

https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/product/src/Entity/ProductType.php

How do I make the ProductType entity revisionable?

I've found this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/making-an-entity-revisionable but it seems to be limited in it's explanation.

Comment: Here's a link to the particular record I'm interested in. Notice that only the "label" attribute is wiewable as an anonymous user. https://ihmm-drupal.reginault.com/jsonapi/commerce_product_type/commerce_product_type

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's [JSON:API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi) does not bring it's own authorization logic. It respects and uses all security measures that Drupal has for that data. You find more details on that one in [Security considerations chapter of the module docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/security-considerations).

Drupal Commerce does not provide it's own access management either. Atleast that is what I get from [their docs](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/product-management/access-control).

You should check your field permissions. Maybe they are customized using [Field Permissions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions)? You may want to [Audit Entity Access and Field Access](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/introducing-entity-access-audit-module) as recommended in docs of JSON:API module.

Comment: It seems like this may not be the right solution, as the content_type is a config entity and not a content entity.